# cannot connect: com.github.dockerjava.api.NotFoundException

Tags: docker, phpstorm, laravel-5

I am trying to use the new feature of PHPStorm, which is to develop PHP app using docker.

I have installed the docker integration plugin for PHPStorm, when I try to define the Clouds settings, I get this error:

```
cannot connect: com.github.dockerjava.api.NotFoundException
```

I have checked the app, and its running in the browser normally at:

```
http://192.168.99.100:8090/
```

I didn't specify the certificates folder, as I am using http not https locally.

[image]

Any idea? I am on windows 10, I have installed jdk-7u79-windows-x64, I tried both 32, 64 versions, I got the same error..

Although the machine is up and running..

Answer (score 0):

Try that:
The fastest way to connect is via ssh to the interpreter(Like vagrant):

Follow: https://hub.docker.com/r/jorge07/php7-xdebug-ssh/
Once machine is up:

Add remote interpreter: 
*Languages & frameworks > PHP* 
(Note that php executable in on: /usr/local/bin/php)

Now add a sftp service: 
*Build, Execution, Deployment > Deployment* 
Connect to machine by ssh and map your code folder with the /app folder on interpreter container.

Once you finish, you are done. Good luck!

Comment: I tried to use your image, there is two folders, /var/www/html and /app, I have mapped the app folder in the container to my app folder in the host, however, when I view it in the browser as http://192.168.99.100:9000/ I get webpage is not available.

I tried to add index.html in the /var/www/html but I got the same result that the webpage is not available..

Would you please write some documentation to use at https://hub.docker.com/r/jorge07/php7-xdebug-ssh/ , ex: with Laravel.. how to run composer commands in the container.. , thanks

Comment: I also tried to ssh into the machine using root and jarco as password at port 2222, kindly check image above in the edit

Comment: I created this repo, Its a symfony application but I think you can remove symfony and use it with laravel: https://github.com/jorge07/symfony3-docker-starter

There is documentation for composer run inside container.

Hope to be more useful